# "with open() as" and indentation

Tags: python, coding-style, indentation

I could not find any official recommended indentation for the following idiom (straight from http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm):

```
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```

or:

```
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.read()
do something with data
```

IMHO, the first version is better at showing the scope, but the latter may prevent an excessive indentation. Is choosing one of those just a matter of taste? Or is there any authoritative source or established tradition to follow?

---

As a side note, I cannot help but think that [with](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) is quite apart from the other block-constructing Python keywords. For instance, there is no question about choosing between:

```
if condition:
    do something
    do something different
```

or:

```
if condition:
    do something
do something different
```

Since they do... well, something different.

Comment: If you (have to) worry about excessive indentation (because of `do something` consisting of many lines) you should probably put the loop and the `something` into separate functions/methods, and make `data` a (return) parameter. Voilà, the scope is well defined then.

Comment: @Murphy Probably, yes. Note that "do something with data" is taken literally (there is no `do` loop in Python). I've taken this example from: http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Indentation doesn't *show* the scope, it *defines* it. Version 1 isn't any better at showing the scope, it just needlessly extends it. The fact that `data` originally came from a file doesn't mean that you need to keep the file opened while you process `data`.

Comment: Your last paragraph is completely wrong. The with block behaves the same as the if block, your first two samples are **not** doing quite the same thing.

Comment: If you are really only opening a file and doing a single read without catching any exceptions, you can just do `data = open(path).read()`.  This is equivalent to your second example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I always use the second approach because it ensures that I don't hold the resource (file in your case) open longer than necessary.

Comment: This is definitely the answer. Made the mistake in a SE answer this very day, by the way. Also, the with statement itself is NOT failsafe, it can throw file exceptions that you need to properly handle, something that is very easy to forget.

Answer (score 7):

In python indentation affect how the program works.

```
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.read()
    do something with data
```

means: open path in f, read in data, do stuff with data, close f

and

```
with open(path) as f:
    data = f.read()
do something with data
```

means: open path in f, read in data, close f, do stuff with data. (I like this more, as i prefer to close files as soon as possible)

So they are not strictly equivalent: indentation in the magical world of python matters as much as curly braces in C-like languages.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. To make the difference appear, one could try to re-open the file in the 3rd line. Which is not quite what I meant with "do something with data", but I cannot find a better example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment. I agree that it saves resources to close the file first and then process the data. However, I think the first approach (that keeps the file open) is more preferable if you have a large file. See [How can I read large text files in Python, line by line, without loading it into memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Not quite.  f.read() is reading the whole file into memory.  To save memory usage, you could implement a loop and use f.readline() (or f.read(100)), but you have to be able to do something with that chunk (and then throw it away before loading the next chunk) or all you've done is read the whole thing into memory, but slower.

Comment: "*the second approach (that keeps the file open)*" ?  It's the *first* approach that keeps the file open.

Comment: @ChrisMurray; you don't need to call `.read()` or `.readline()`, you can more easily just `for line in file:`.

Comment: @ChrisMurray Thanks for pointing it out. I think it is a typo.